# Program that calls integers and uses function to add a number to user input crashing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Okay so I am trying to make my program ask for user integers (all working fine) and then call the function, which adds 5 to each array element, which i think is fine? then i need to print in the main program: the original integers with 5 added to them. anyone see what is wrong? my program crashes

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FUN(int ARR2[]);

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  int ARR1[20];
  printf("Please enter 20 integers.\n");

  for(i=0; i<20; i++) // switch back to 20
  {
    scanf("%i", &ARR1[i]);
  }

  FUN(&ARR1[i]);
  printf("The new numbers are: %i", ARR1[i]);

  return 0;
}

void FUN(int ARR2[])
{
    int i=0;
    ARR2[20];

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        ARR2[i]+=5;
}
```

Comment: What error or debug info do you get when it crashes?

Comment: `FUN(&ARR1[i]);` : `i` is 20, this is out of bound. just call `FUN(ARR1);` then print use for-loop;

Comment: ARR2[20]; line2 from function FUN() looks like the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach this line

```
FUN(&ARR1[i]);
```

the value of your `i` variable is 20 so you are accessing the 21st element in `ARR` which is probably giving you an access violation. If you replace this line with

```
FUN(ARR1);
```

and remove the line

```
ARR2[20];
```

from your function `FUN` you might get the behaviour you are expecting

Comment: Also he needs to get rid of `ARR2[20];`

Comment: I figured it out with your help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

After your first for loop, `i` get's the value `20` but `ARR1` is indexed `0` to `19`. So, you might get a Segmentation Fault when you call

```
FUN(&ARR1[i]);
```

You should change that to

```
FUN(ARR1);
```

Also, in your function `void FUN(int ARR2[])` , you have

```
ARR2[20];
```

Which also causes this error. Remove it.

You are also giving output the wrong way. You are doing

```
printf("The new numbers are: %i", ARR1[i]);
```

which also tries to access `ARR1[20]` , again causing problems.

You should change it to

```
  printf("The new numbers are: \n");
  for ( i=0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
     printf("%d\n", ARR1[i]);
```

You should change your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FUN(int ARR2[]);

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  int ARR1[20];
  printf("Please enter 20 integers.\n");

  for(i=0; i<20; i++) // switch back to 20
  {
    scanf("%i", &ARR1[i]);
  }

  FUN(ARR1);
  printf("The new numbers are: \n");
  for ( i=0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
     printf("%d\n", ARR1[i]);

  return 0;
}

void FUN(int ARR2[])
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        ARR2[i]+=5;
}
```